# Terminating UDP Stop and wait

Tags: udp

I am coding a stop and wait UDP file transfer.

Everytime i send a packet, ill start a timeout timer and wait for acks. If i recv an ack, ill transmit the next packet. If i recv a nack or did not recv acks, once my timeout expires, ill retransfer the packet.

For the receivers end, whenever i recv a packet, ill transmit a ack when checksum and seq number tallies. Else a nack.

This is my school assignment, to code a udp file transfer with error detection.
So dont ask me to use tcp.

The problem is when i want to end the connection. Once the last packet has been sent, ill now send a EOF message to the receiver, signalling the end of file transfer. So i send the EOF message, and start the timer. The reciver, receives the EOF message, sends back an ACK message and shutsdown. However, if this ACK message gets discarded, the sender is gonna timeout and will repeatedly resend the EOF message. How do i go about preventing this?